# Qooxdoo - Does calling getInstance() multiple times cause a memory leak?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a application that updates every X min. In the update routine, it calls multiple qx classes that are singletons with the getInstance() method. Is that something that would be causing a slow memory leak?

Note: Firefox v18 and IE8 (the only version I've tested with) will crash after about 24-30 hours of the application running, but for some reason Chrome v25 seems to do alright. Here is the site I'm referring to: preview.weather.gov/edd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be the cause of your memory leaks. The implementation of `getInstance()` within qooxdoo (and per definition) is very simple. As general rule of thumb try to call `dispose()` on qooxdoo objects you don't need anymore.

Also have a look at the manual (this may be outdated):

- http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.1.1/pages/development/memory_management.html#finding-memory-leaks
- http://qooxdoo.org/docs/general/snippets#support_for_finding_potential_memory_leaks

Comment: Thanks, those pages helped a lot - specifically this was very useful: qx.dev.Debug.startDisposeProfiling()  and qx.dev.Debug.stopDisposeProfiling()